# Dotnet core with monodevelop

Tags: .net-core, monodevelop

Can you use dotnet core with monodevelop? How can I go about working with dotnet core's csproj files with monodevelop? When I use monodevelop 6.3 and I open the csproj file, I see no other files in the project.

Comment: You asked this question at an improper time. Microsoft's focus is now Visual Studio for Windows and for Mac to deliver .NET Core development, or you can use Visual Studio Code for basic editing. The future of MonoDevelop is not quite clear to me.

Comment: The latest versions of MonoDevelop support DotNet Core, the git tags are under `monodevelop-7.0.0.XXXX`. There are about 6 releases under 7.0 so far, these parallel the alpha/preview releases for *Visual Studio for Mac*. Since these are alpha/preview releases, you either need to build it from source or try the CI versions (Ubuntu based) from the public jenkins server https://jenkins.mono-project.com//job/test-monodevelop-mainline/ http://www.monodevelop.com/download/ci-packages/

Comment: I have 7.8, can someone please write an answer of how to actually do this?